# In a topological space $X, G$ is open iff $G\cap\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{G\cap A}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> In a topological space $X$, $G$ is open iff $G\cap\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{G\cap A}$, where
>   $A$ is an arbitrary set in $X$.

To prove this I started from definition of an open set, I could not complete it.
I even tried to prove it in metric space using def I could not complete it

Comment: What’s $A$? ...

Comment: A is a set in X

Comment: Is $A$ a **specific** set in $X$, or is the condition supposed to be "if **for all** subsets $A$ of $X$, we have that $G\cap \overline{A}\subseteq \overline {G\cap A}$?

Comment: for all subsets 

Comment: Try it with $A=X-G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $A=X-G$. Then $G\cap A=\varnothing$, so $\overline{G\cap A}=\varnothing$. Therefore, you must have $G\cap\overline{A}=\varnothing$. This means that $\overline{X-G} = \overline{A}\subseteq X-G$, hence $\overline{X-G}=X-G$. That is, the complement of $G$ is closed.

Conversely, suppose that $G$ is open, and let $A$ be arbitrary. Let $x\in G\cap \overline{A}$. To show that $x\in \overline{G\cap A}$, we just need to show that any open set that contains $x$ will intersect $G\cap A$ nontrivially. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open set containing $x$. Then $\mathcal{O}\cap G$ is an open set containing $x$ (since $x\in G$), so $\mathcal{O}\cap G\cap A\neq\varnothing$ (since $x\in\overline{A}$). Thus, $\mathcal{O}\cap (G\cap A)\neq\varnothing$. This proves that $x\in\overline{G\cap A}$, giving the desired inclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $G \cap \overline{A} \subset \overline{G\cap A} $ then
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\begin{aligned}
G \cap \overline{A} \subset \overline{G\cap A} & \Longleftrightarrow X \backslash (\overline{G\cap A}) \subset X \backslash ( G \cap \overline{A}) \Longleftrightarrow X \backslash int(G \cap A) \subset X \backslash ( G \cap \overline{A})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Take $A = X$ then 
\begin{equation}
X \backslash int(G) = X \backslash int(G \cap X) \subset X \backslash G \cap \overline{X} =  X \backslash G ,
\end{equation}
 i. e., $G \subset int(G)$ and therefore $G$ is open.

Comment: I don't see how you justify the third $\iff$? $\mathrm{int}(G\cap A)\subseteq \overline{G\cap A}$, so $X\setminus\mathrm{int}(G\cap A)\supseteq X\setminus(\overline{G\cap A})$. So I don't see it...  Note that $A=X$ just gives you $G\subseteq \overline{G}$, which of course holds for any $G$...

Comment: Look: for $A=X$, your chain of implications reads: $G\subseteq\overline{G}\iff X\setminus\overline{G}\subseteq X\setminus G$ (I agree with that); and $X\setminus\overline{G}\subseteq X\setminus G\iff X\setminus\mathrm{int}(G)\subseteq X\setminus G$. But the first term in your chain is **always** true, and the last term in your chain is true **only** if $G$ is open. So you are *assuming* that $G$ is open in order to assert all three terms are equivalent.. But "$G$ is open" is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Note that $X \backslash A \subset \overline{ X \backslash A}$, hence $X \backslash (\overline{X \backslash A}) \subset A$. Thus,$ X \backslash (\overline{X \backslash A})$ is an open content in $A$, therefore, $X \backslash (\overline{X \backslash A}) \subset int (A)$. Taking supplements again,
We conclude that $X \backslash int (A) \subset \overline{ X \backslash A}$.

Comment: But that is not what you have: you have $X\setminus\mathrm{int}(G\cap A)$ and $X\setminus\overline{G\cap A}$; you would need $X\setminus\mathrm{int}(G\cap A)$ and $\overline{X\setminus(G\cap A)}$. Again: plug in $X=A$ into your chain of implications to see that the first term is **always** true but the last term, *as written* is true **if and only if** $G$ is open.

Comment: For the other content, such as $int (A) \subset A$, you have to $X \backslash A \subset X \backslash int (A)$. Also, since $X \backslash int (A)$ is closed, it has to \overline{X \ A} \subset X \ int (A)$.

Comment: It's wrong. You are confusing $\overline{X\setminus (G\cap A)}$ with $X\setminus\overline{G\cap A}$.